# The watch command incorrectly placed the terminal content and made an error

Tags: linux, shell, watch

My code is:

```
watch -g -n 1 "cat ${OUTPUT_INFO_PATH}/$OUTPUTLOG/last_run_init.txt | grep -o 'DOPRA VISP Version'" > /dev/null
```

It will cause some problem :

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it, let it display normal

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `reset`. It's ok if nothing shows up when you type, just write it anyways and hit enter.

Terminals have a number of special settings that programs can change. Normally, they change them back when they exit. If they don't, the terminal output may be temporarily corrupted.

You can simulate this by running `stty raw` or `stty -echo`, which makes the prompt look corrupted like in your screenshots. You can get it back to normal with `reset`.

Comment: Thank you , I have try， but how to avoid this situation when I use the watch

Comment: It shouldn't normally happen. I don't even know why you are getting any output when you run `watch` with `> /dev/null`